# Installing jupyter notebook shows command not found

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

Im trying to install jupyter notebook but when I run jupyter/jupyter-notebook/jupyter notebook It shows command not found. I'm using python 3.7 and have tried all commands like :

```
pip install jupyter              
pip3 install jupyter
python -m pip install jupter notebook
pip install --user jupyter
sudo pip install jupyter
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6O15S.png)

It shows an exception error I don't know why?

Comment: It shows "command not found" because the installation failed. It looks like you're using `pip` from the OS X system Python (2.7) *and* trying to install for Python 3.7, which will not work. It's impossible to guess how you got into that situation, though, and difficult to give any advice on how to get out of it.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using cmd to install?
If yes, then you want to install the classic Jupyter Notebook using:

```
pip install notebook
```

Then, you can run with:

```
jupyter notebook
jupyter-notebook
py -m jupyter notebook
py -m jupyter-notebook
python -m jupyter notebook
python -m jupyter-notebook
```

That works fine for me. Tell me if you still have problems.